# Stirling Number Proof Help Needed

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, stirling-numbers

Show that, for $m > 0, S(m, 2) = 2^m-1$ Give a complete proof.

(Question is about Stirling numbers)

I have attached whatever I tried to do:

[image: derivation_of_Stirling_number_of_the_second_kind_for_two_sets]

But it's not giving me the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

You have correctly shown that $S(m,2) = \frac12(2^m - 2) = 2^{m-1}-1$. Whoever told you it should be $2^m - 1$ is wrong.

We can also see this a different way. $S(m,2)$ counts the number of ways to partition $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ into two nonempty subsets. The two subsets are not distinguishable, so call the subset containing $1$ the *first* subset and the other subset the *second* subset.

For each of $2,3,\dots,m$, we have a choice between putting it in either the first subset or the second, for $2^{m-1}$ possibilities. (In other words, each of $2, 3, \dots, m$ can either be put in the *same* subset as $1$, or in a *different* subset.) However, one of the $2^{m-1}$ possibilities is forbidden: we can't put all of them in the first subset, because the second subset must also be nonempty. This gives another proof that $S(m,2) = 2^{m-1}-1$.

Comment: In this proof, how do we know that there is no duplication of subsets?

Comment: For each of $2, \dots, m$, you choose whether they are in the same subset as $1$ or not. The set of those answers uniquely determines the partition, except that you have to exclude the partition $\{\{1,\dots,m\}, \varnothing\}$.

Comment: got it. thanks.